# Using Typescript, how can require a property when a specific value for another property is provided?

Tags: typescript

I have created a type for a Button component which can be rendered as a button or anchor element. When a button is created using a specific variant, the "subtle" variant, I am requiring that the `level` property is provided. I think I'm pretty close to getting the types right, but when I choose "subtle" as the variant (without specifying the `level`), it should show an error telling me that the level is missing, but it instead tells me that the `href` is missing. How can I get the types to be correct for what I am trying to accomplish?

Here's the cases I want to cover for the Button component:

1. Rendered as a button element

   - This can be a normal button

     - Identified by picking any variant other than "subtle"
   - This can be a subtle button

     - Requires the level property to be provided
2. Anchor element that looks like a button

   - Rendered when the href is present AND type is not present
   - This can be a normal button

     - Identified by picking any variant other than "subtle"
   - This can be a subtle button

     - Requires the level property to be provided

[Check out the TS playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAQmAu8D2IBqAmVBDATgSyxHigG8AoKKABXwlwE8oBeKAchrzp3tYBoKoAZWABjFABMGzNsLEhJ3PgIAiwAM7wcYEfDwA3YNNaqNWnfuBLKgsACN4AG0MtWN+06tQAKsAAexFx9-JQBfMjJQSFgEZDR0QTwAL0Nya2gXQToHB08AWXEjXOBxPEhPABkAcyNy3ErLfjCI8Gg4RBQMcuADB1IBAC1gHCQjAAZPAHkQZzYARk8vAHcRl3RQ8Ph6AAdDNtiMGiQttRgsNRnUqBEACzwHcRxQAC4oUzwQSoE9XAIiAH4XnsOpgfoR4AI1ElgADou04glkgI8GpykgsCUPjDbEgkE5CGQmpsdrD9uhDscAIJqNyOYBAkDSS7ffBgwExYHYFlEAB0NKcAmujwAZjDpgYcAIidCXqxbOyQKwoAAfNhqOwQPDwRUq1iPc5agROHpsuGdbrABwEjbbXbyg7DSlqAByKD5dPljK+oP+LwAor4RA4wOJgAAeekYTm-eC8Ekc73wXl2WkAPgFwtF5ollClMNl8u1qvVmsLuvUwANlCNFsz4qtZClcbi5LUVPp0gjZIdJzOhgAZAIABSdltUt3tlUj7tUl0gcfygCU1uJU6Orepyac9IpIBuSBwnsozOjJtJUbBSfcwHTwCFLzeH0lNtrQ0N5ocp+BXR69YA9L-vAmZQJheAAxPBKjAR4oCQBAoEWa5GE1KB4FuEAAGs1BQ65DEFW8oGRKBHgARzAPBHgKBDQCgLAhE3Qw5ThAisLAc5xFjKiGWQtRrlg+4YJABxGBIsjoNQwxq0tRtV0dWd5zhHc9wPFgmQTGF-UDYMw07c8iFjHSE0vVMbzvV5NHeT4c2fF4xVfKt3xfCVCRtJt7TXKlFN45TXK7NdTnOKAB0oYc7V8x15NiTz92VHzR2dV16O3XcvKXBsXJkrCWAytsPUnUK4qiiUyDkDQoBAfcsnpT9m27Q8rlue5HhAGV2yCLVGnCEriDVK8qti2qVK9Ll4GqyNDLdfhKBuO4HmeNhWr8dr6y6qBGMi1sQEK0awsyvpKDw0zWGuRBjief9Fgu7lKhxSonG5MQIE8abGrm1gFuCDripQUqetpbcNq2-q1zq49WR83TEwmkyZWO+BTvOy7rqQW7gHupBHtjARntm5r5o9NrQiAA).

```js
export enum ButtonV2Variant {
  Primary = 'Primary',
  Secondary = 'Secondary',
  Destructive = 'Destructive',
  Subtle = 'Subtle',
  Text = 'Text',
}

export enum ButtonV2Size {
  Sm = 'Small',
  Md = 'Medium',
  Lg = 'Large',
}

export enum ButtonV2Level {
  Zero = '0',
  One = '1',
  Two = '2',
}

type ButtonV2PropsBase = {
  children: string
  variant?: ButtonV2Variant
  size?: ButtonV2Size
  isLoading?: boolean
  leftIconName?: IconName
  rightIconName?: IconName
}

type ButtonV2PropsAsSubtleButton = {
  variant: ButtonV2Variant.Subtle
  href?: never
  type?: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset'
  level: ButtonV2Level
}

type ButtonV2PropsAsNonSubtleButton = {
  variant?: Exclude<ButtonV2Variant, ButtonV2Variant.Subtle>
  href?: never
  type?: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset'
  level?: never
}

type ButtonV2PropsAsButton = ButtonV2PropsBase &
  React.ComponentProps<'button'> &
  (ButtonV2PropsAsSubtleButton | ButtonV2PropsAsNonSubtleButton)

type ButtonV2PropsAsSubtleButtonAnchor = {
  variant: ButtonV2Variant.Subtle
  href: string
  type?: never
  level: ButtonV2Level
}

// TODO: Figure out why it thinks the href is required when a Subtle button is used, when it should only require the level
type ButtonV2PropsAsNonSubtleButtonAnchor = {
  variant?: Exclude<ButtonV2Variant, ButtonV2Variant.Subtle>
  href: string
  type?: never
  level?: never
}

type ButtonV2PropsAsAnchor = ButtonV2PropsBase &
  React.ComponentProps<'a'> &
  (ButtonV2PropsAsSubtleButtonAnchor | ButtonV2PropsAsNonSubtleButtonAnchor)

type ButtonV2Props = ButtonV2PropsAsButton | ButtonV2PropsAsAnchor
```

Comment: Have you considered adding `as` prop? Currently, the anchor and button have no distinguishable structure, adding `as: "button" | "a"` would fix the issue like in [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nd8GyN). Does this approach work for you?

Comment: That's an interesting idea @wonderflame, but I don't think that will work quite well. This requires me to provide the `as` prop every time the component is used. In 95% of the time, it will always be a button though, so I would like to provide an automatic default value of "button" but then the same issue as before comes back if it's optional.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying exactly where and what the problem in the code is?  I see two errors, but they correspond exactly to what I'd expect.  The error tells you that *both* `href` *and* `level` are missing.  If you are upset that it mentions `href` *in addition* to `level`, then could you write that and not "instead" (but this would be asking for a bit much, imo)?  Unless you see something different, in which case, could you demonstrate that?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I think you hit the nail on the head. The only real issue is that when it's a subtle button (which is determined by the absence of the href), I don't want it to require the href. Should I just make the `href` optional in `ButtonV2PropsAsSubtleButtonAnchor`?

Comment: I'm confused: [`href` is demonstrably not required](https://tsplay.dev/w1x22W). When you write an *incorrect* `ButtonV2Props`, the compiler has to figure out *how* it's incorrect, and there are multiple possible ways to correct it. One way is to make it a valid `ButtonV2PropsAsSubtleButtonAnchor`, which wants an `href` and a `level`. You can't easily control which union member the compiler picks in the error message, and I'm not sure why you want to even try.  If you could please [edit] the question to clarify *exactly* why it matters (given that it does *not* requires `href`), it might help.